# Unable to fix package path error in Android Studio

Tags: android

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, all the imports of LipeRMI classes are in vain. What should be the right path statement to have them imported correctly?
I face the same error in `MainActivity` for:

`import lipermi.handler.CallHandler;
import lipermi.net.Client;`

I know such questions regarding android studio have been asked many times but I just fail to understand how to fix this problem. 
FYI, I dragged the `net.sf.lipermi` folder into `com.example.akash.chatapplication` folder.

Thank you for your time. :)

**EDIT**- After following Tanis.7x's answer, this is the updated hierarchy as well as the MainActivity code-
[image]

Comment: Have you declared the LipeRMI dependency in `build.gradle`?

Comment: No I don't know exactly what do I need to type in there. :/ @bigdestroyer

Comment: @Gavriel I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By dragging the `net.sf.lipermi` folder into the `com.example.akash.chatapplication` folder, you have altered the package for those classes.

This won't compile, because the folder path needs to match these classes' package declaration. This this case, the package would have to be `com.example.akash.chatapplication.net.sf.lipermi`, which is clearly not what you want.

If you really need to copy these classes into your project, you should copy them into the `src/main` folder instead of into your application's package.

The best route is to include these files as a dependency in your `build.gradle`. However, not all libraries offer this option. If that library provides a JAR file, you should instead include that JAR in your project's `libs` folder. Including the raw source in your project should always be a last resort.

Comment: The first part of the problem has been fixed, while the second part  `import lipermi.handler.CallHandler;
import lipermi.net.Client;` still remains unsolved after dragging the lipeRMI folder to src/main.

Comment: These two lines are in `MainActivity.java` as shown in the image.

Comment: If you moved the whole `net/sf/lipermi` tree into `src/main`, then the correct import would be `net.sf.lipermi.handler.CallHandler`, not `lipermi.handler.CallHandler`.

Comment: That's not working. I'm assuming it's because `main.net.sf.lipermi` is in `main` and the path for the java class is `main.java.com.example.akash.chatapplication.MainActivity.java`.

Comment: `main` should be a part of the package, unless you have a `main` folder within your `main` folder.

Comment: You've gotten me all wrong on that point. I'm just telling you the path, there's only 1 main folder. I've updated my question.
Thank you for staying with me for this long :)

Comment: Ah, woops. Try moving it under the `java` directory. The `net` folder should be in the same place as the `com` folder.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for getting back to you this late.

Answer (score 1):

you should move `src/main/com/example/akash/chatapplication/net` to `src/main`

Comment: Could you please refer to my comment on Tanis.7x's answer?

Comment: please include code from MainActivity so we can help and not just guess